# Error while executing my SQL select from php

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute SQL in $stmt from phpmyadmin, it works fine and I get the desired result. However, from PHP it is going in the exception code block. Also, `mysqli_error` or `mysqli_errno` is blank.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "1 - Started \r\n");

function processMessage($update) {

    $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Inside processMessage \r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    if($update["result"]["action"] == ""){

        $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', $update["result"]["parameters"]["plannumber"]."\r\n", FILE_APPEND );

        $planNo = $update["result"]["parameters"]["plannumber"];

        $stmt = "select count(*) AS reccount from plandetails where plannumber = '$planNo'";

        $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Statement=".$stmt."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$stmt);

        $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Result=".$result."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

        if (!$result) {

            $errno = mysqli_errno($connection);

            $fp = file_put_contents('1.log',"Error in Select Query: ". $errno . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
            exit;

        }

        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $count = $data['reccount'];

        $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Count=".$count."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

        If ($count > 0) {
            $speech = 'What is your Member ID';
        }
        else {
            $speech = 'Plan Number $planNo not found';
        }

        $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Speech=".$speech, FILE_APPEND);

            sendMessage(array(
                "source" => $update["result"]["source"],
                //"speech" => $update["result"]["parameters"]["plannumber"],
                "speech" => $speech,
                "displayText" => "........Text Here...........",
                "contextOut" => array()
            ));
    }

}

function sendMessage($parameters) {
    $req_dump = print_r($parameters, true);
    $fp = file_put_contents( 'Response.log', $req_dump);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($parameters);
}

//open DB connection
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "XXXX";
    $password = "XXXX";
    $database = "XXXX";

    $connection = mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        $con_errno = mysqli_connect_error();
        file_put_contents('1.log',"Error in DB Connection: " . $con_errno. "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        exit();
    }

$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
$fp = file_put_contents('input.log', $update_response);

$update = json_decode($update_response, true);

if (isset($update["result"]["action"])) {
    $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Inside isset:".$update."\r\n");
    processMessage($update);
}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Help community to help you: a) submit "SQL in $stmt from phpmyadmin, it works fine" b)  `going in the exception code block` - which lines exactly?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the function processMessage, what is $connection's value? its not a global variable and you are not passing it into the function as parameter

Comment: Once I got connection code inside function and commented $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Result=".$result."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); It started working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad you got it working :) reason you are not getting anyhing in log file for query result is because the $result is an object not a string like you are trying to do.  see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

I brought the entire connection thing inside processMessage function (given below) and it still doesn't work. Statement is getting logged correctly in log file but $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Result=".$result."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); is not in log file.

```
    $planNo = $update["result"]["parameters"]["plannumber"];

    //open DB connection
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxx";
    $database = "xxxx";

    $connection = mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        $con_errno = mysqli_connect_error();
        file_put_contents('1.log',"Error in DB Connection: " . $con_errno. "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = "select count(*) AS reccount from plandetails where plannumber = '$planNo'";

    $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Statement=".$stmt."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$stmt);

    $fp = file_put_contents('1.log', "Result=".$result."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```